# Tensorflow: get model losses on epoch begin

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I created an autoencoder class by subclassing `tf.keras.models.Model` in `tensorflow v2.16.1`. Within the `call` function, I used the `Model.add_loss` to add losses to my model. Here is the class definition:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, losses

tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()

class Autoencoder(tf.keras.models.Model):
    def __init__(self, nlayers, shape, use_bias=False):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape = shape
        self.encoder = tf.keras.Sequential()
        for n in range(nlayers):
            layer_i = layers.Dense(
                int(np.round(shape[0] / (2 ** (n + 1)))),
                activation="relu",
            )
            self.encoder.add(layer_i)
        self.decoder = tf.keras.Sequential()
        for n in range(nlayers, 0, -1):
            layer_i = layers.Dense(
                int(np.round(shape[0] / (2 ** (n - 1)))),
                activation="sigmoid",
            )
            self.decoder.add(layer_i)

    def call(self, X):
        encoded = self.encoder(X)
        decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
        self.add_loss(losses.MeanSquaredError(reduction="sum")(X, decoded))
        return decoded

class LossLogger(callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
        logs = logs or {}
        if self.model.losses:
            mse_loss = self.model.losses[0].numpy()
        else:
            mse_loss = None
        logs.update({"mse_loss": mse_loss})
```

To access the values of loss function, I use the `model.losses[0].numpy()`. However, I received the error message:

> AttributeError: 'SymbolicTensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

Based on other posts, I included `tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()` in my code, and verified that `tf.executing_eagerly()` returns `True`. But I haven't found a true solution yet.

How can I get the values of losses that I defined using `add_loss` function? I would like to log them using a callback function. Does there exist any other way apart from converting to `numpy`, something like `model.losses[0].asscalar()`?

P.S. I use the add_loss function because I use sum of multiple losses in my code, some that are losses built-in to tensorflow, while others are custom